# Run a script on PythonAnywhere within a html file

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, web-applications, flask

I'm trying to run a python script using Flask framework.
The main goal is to:

- Submit data (keyword) + click a button
- Put the keyword on python script
- Run it on the server
- Return back a response
- Request the result (Json)
- Print result on html page

**Some notes:**

The script is a request from a third party API
The result that I want to print in the html page is just a number.

**API Script:**

```
import indicoio
indicoio.config.api_key = 'YOUR_API_KEY'

# single example
print.indicoio.sentiment("Keyword")
```

After some research I found 2 solutions to my problem but I don't know how to implement the code. I'm a beginner, easy on me please.

**My App.py**

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path="/static", static_folder='/home/dubspher/mysite/static')

@app.route('/')
def static_file():
    return app.send_static_file('index.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

**First Approach:**

```
pip install requests
import requests
data = {"keyword":"LoremIpsum"}
r = requests.put("Request_Page_Link/",data = data )
data = r.json 
print("data")
```

**Second Approach:**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/my-link/')
def my_link():
  print 'I got clicked!'

  return 'Click.'

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(debug=True)
```

**Code to handle POST and GET request:**

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="name">
<button type="button" id="home" onclick="validate()" value="checkvalue">
<script>
$('#id').click(function(){

 $.ajax({
      type:'get',
      url:<YOUR SERVERSIDE PAGE URL>,
      cache:false,
      data:<if any arguments>,
      async:asynchronous,
      dataType:json, //if you want json
      success: function(data) {
        <put your custom validation here using the response from data structure >
      },
      error: function(request, status, error) {
        <put your custom code here to handle the call failure>
      }
   });
});
</script>
```

Let me know if I need to add more informations. Thanks!

Comment: I see you are trying ajax method to call the server. Okay what stopping now?

Comment: @raja-simon I've never worked with ajax and seriously I do not know where to start.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use fetch it's pure javascript to make the url call in js. And you can do the GET call like `fetch('/my-link')`

```
fetch('/my-link')
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.json()
  }).then(function(json) {
    console.log('parsed json', json)
  }).catch(function(ex) {
    console.log('parsing failed', ex)
  })
```

In your view do some processing and `return jsonify(dict)` output/

Comment: Should I create a specific page (my_link) that handle post and get ?

Comment: You have already created my-link url handler and that returns now click right ?

Comment: All I have done is deploy a static html using flask, I have been learning python for 1 week :(

Comment: Oh that's great. So you have to know how to create website ( including templates and static and render view )

Comment: What is your specific question now?

Comment: I know how to use render_template stuff. I'm a fast-learner. My question is how to get from point A to B? I mean just a step by step. I can google the code needed for every step! Thanks btw.

Comment: Okay try google if you can't find the answers let me know here... Okay ?

Comment: I'm away from my lap. Will check it